# TFS Database migration miss the detach step issue

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, team-foundation-server, sql-server-2012

We currently doing the TFS database migration, originally, we suppose to upgrade to 2012 which support SQL 2008 R2, after a period of time, we decide to upgrade to 2013, and unfortunately we are upgrade on the rush and forget forget to detach the Collection in 2008 by upgrade to SQL 2012, is there anyway we could get that database back and reattched to TFS 2013? many thanks in advance cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You should never do a detach-attach upgrade as it is not a primary supported path and has many problems.

You need to backup and restore the entire instance to the new server and then install 2013. Run tgebsetup wizard and you are good to go.

You will need to bring across at least your tfs_configuration and all of your collections together.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620932.aspx

Note: It is not possible to attach a collection that was not detached. You need to either go back to a working instance or raise a paied support ticket with Microsoft.